# Can Christians manufacture cigarettes?

Tags: christian-living

My husband and I were discussing an essay my nephew wrote where he says he wants to manufacture cigarettes. I thought it was a good dream but shouldn't we address whether this is something that is good to people who use them? My husband said there is nothing wrong with manufacturing cigarettes because the bible doesn't forbid it. Are there verses that are relevant to my question?

Comment: Please [edit] this to break it up into proper sentences.

Comment: Also, this is totally a "Is X a sin?" question, and just not what we do here. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible that Christians may disagree about this issue, with some claiming verses such as:

> Command those who are rich in this present world not to be arrogant nor to put their hope in wealth, which is so uncertain, but to put their hope in **God**, who **richly provides us with *everything* for our enjoyment**. - [1 Timothy 6:17 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Timothy%206%3A17&version=NIV) (emphasis added)

could be interpreted to grant implicit permission towards smoking cigarettes and that therefore their manufacture is morally neutral and an acceptable occupation to engage in; this is a considerably more difficult case to maintain since it has become common knowledge that [smoking cigarettes is **harmful**](http://betobaccofree.hhs.gov/health-effects/smoking-health/).

Of considerable relevance to a Christian's consideration of whether an occupation is consistent with Biblical principles are the following:

> 35 One of them, an expert in the law, tested him with this question: 36 “Teacher, which is the greatest commandment in the Law?”
>
> 37 Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ 38 This is the first and greatest commandment. 39 And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ 40 All the Law and the Prophets hang on these two commandments.” - [Matthew 22:35-40 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2022%3A35-40&version=NIV)
>
> **Love does no harm** to a neighbor. Therefore love is the fulfillment of the law. - [Romans 13:10 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom%2013%3A10&version=NIV) (emphasis added)

Many would argue that taken together, the fact that cigarettes are known to be harmful  and the importance of loving our neighbor in a way that does them no harm constitute a strong reason that a Christian should not engage in the manufacture of cigarettes.

Answer (score -1):

**Life and Death**

> And in vain they worship Me, Teaching as doctrines the commandments of men. (Mark 7:7 NKJV)

Cigarettes are considered harmful because of the Cancer. This however has been shown to me. They smoke their cigarettes because of their Anxiety. Those trusting on an outside source to relieve their anxiety will not enter into the Kingdom of Heaven.

**Let us Dissect**

> Now the works of the flesh are evident, which are: adultery, fornication, uncleanness, lewdness, 20 idolatry, sorcery, hatred, contentions, jealousies, outbursts of wrath, selfish ambitions, dissensions, heresies, 21 envy, murders, drunkenness, revelries, and the like; of which I tell you beforehand, just as I also told you in time past, that those who practice such things will not inherit the kingdom of God. (Galatians 5:19-21 NKJV)

No matter how you attempt to reduce your "Anxiety" whether it be by CIGARETTES, vitamins, prescription medicines, over the counter drugs, illegal drugs, alcohol, partying, legal or illegal sex, orgies, strip clubs, homosexuality, adultery, legal or illegal pornography, bestiality, necrophilia, power struggles, rivalry, hostile fits of rage, dissension from authority, joining a clique, slandering others, satisfying the desire for objects of adoration, wanting what others have (even stuff at the store), pride over what you have, soft things of adoration, stealing to obtain possessions, wanting in general and not being satisfied, cheating others out of money, killing people, abortion, sacrificing children to false gods, or lying to get your way.

All of these forms of "Relief" only satisfy the result of Denial(Finding Error to a Process). Yet the cure for denial is "Faith" for those that believe do not suffer the symptoms of denial. All this is proven by the stages of grief, and the polarization of faith and anxiety.

Here is logic, if the cure for anxiety is of a thing, when the thing is not present then anxiety because the cure is not present can still occur. Therefore the only cure for anxiety must be with us always. As is the truth in the teachings that the Jesus gave us. For I am in reality and the truth is in me (Ref: John 14:11).

**Wait Jesus Drank!**

> The Son of Man came eating and drinking, and they say, ‘Look, a glutton and a winebibber, a friend of tax collectors and sinners!’ But wisdom is justified by her children.” (Matthew 11:19 NKJV)

**How can this be!**
There is no command "Do not Drink". But Jesus drank and drunkards do not get to heaven! What does this mean? The difference is "Reliance". If the Attitude of a person is reliant on a thing then it is Idolatry. However if reliant on God, then the Attitude reflects the Holy Spirit. Then one relying on God can drink? Yes. But one relying on the Alcohol for "Spiritual Release" is under condemnation? Yes.

**So how does this connect to Cigarettes?**
The same goes for Cigarettes. If the reason you are smoking is because you need relief from the "Tension of Anxiety" you will die. If your smoking for Love then you are not condemned.

**What about the Manufacturing of Cigarettes?**
Let us look to the fruits of the Breath.

> But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, gentleness, self-control. Against such there is no law. (Galatians 5:22-23 NKJV)

Can the Holy Attitudes be maintained while manufacturing the Cigarettes? I think so.

> “Again I say to you that if two of you agree on earth concerning anything that they ask, it will be done for them by My Father in heaven. (Matthew 18:19 NKJV)

So if there is agreement between the two of you that making Cigarettes is OK then it is allowed by God. But if there is disagreement then making Cigarettes is condemned.

**People "Can Have" "Their Own" perspectives**

> One person esteems one day above another; another esteems every day alike. Let each be fully convinced in his own mind. (Romans 14:5 NKJV)

If the other is convinced then the self may join in to that understanding. If the self finds error then because "Anxiety is Destroyed by Faith", the self can do what is from Love. Yet if you lack faith as many do, then do not do it. For "Anxiety Begs for Death".

**To be of one mind**

> Now I plead with you, brethren, by the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that you all speak the same thing, and that there be no divisions among you, but that you be perfectly joined together in the same mind and in the same judgment. (1 Corinthians 1:10 NKJV)

So also the perspective of those around you, if what you do causes them to fall to anxiety are you really loving them? This is What God Said Through Paul about this.

> Therefore, if food makes my brother stumble, I will never again eat meat, lest I make my brother stumble. (1 Corinthians 8:13 NKJV)

Let us say that there is unity between you, your husband, and your nephew that the manufacturing the Cigarettes has been through unity a clean activity. Then it is clean, let us say though that Grandma finds out, and Grandma starts to worry about what you all are doing. Then it is Loving to Grandma to stop, for "Her life is the one in Jeopardy" because of "Her Anxiety". Yet if Grandma although not wanting to join in, agrees. Then it is clean also.

> Greater love has no one than this, than to lay down one’s life for his friends. (John 15:13 NKJV)

When you lay down what you want to do for another you show the greatest Love. That of God. Hope this helps.